# Query git repositories from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a url of my `git` project and I want to create a **list parameter of all the  repositories inside it** for the user selection.
I saw that there is `gitParameter` plugin I can use but it seems to query branches and not repositories.
Is there a way to do it? I'm new to Jenkins and struggle with it...

```
 parameters([
        gitParameter(branch: '',
                     branchFilter: 'origin/(.*)',
                     defaultValue: 'master',
                     description: '',
                     name: 'BRANCH',
                     quickFilterEnabled: false,
                     selectedValue: 'NONE',
                     sortMode: 'NONE',
                     tagFilter: '*',
                     type: 'PT_BRANCH')
    ])
```

Comment: This is not a git but a git(hub|lab|XXXXX) feature. We have no idea where your project are hosted.

Comment: I need the user to select a repository and then a branch...

Comment: That does not answer the question: which backend is hosting your git repostirories ? Listing branches in a repository is a git features. Listing repositories in a "group" is a feature from your gitXXXX hosting provider (github, gitlab, bitbucket....). There might be a plugin for your particular git hosting provider available for Jenkins but the starting point is to know which one. You should edit your question to add this info.

Comment: We use bitbucket and it exposes git interface. In Jenkins git parameter plugin etc. works

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: https://plugins.jenkins.io/bitbucket/

Comment: This is not a scalable solution you should not be considering it. Maybe what you are looking for is the `webhook` feature, where code push itself will trigger the job with respective repo, branch in jenkins job. Please describe in detail what is the requirement to select repo name as a `Build Parameter` , if you want to badly do it you can consider using `choice` parameter but its again inflexible if you want to specify a lot of different feature branches.